# Fail a merge or build if a particular file has changed?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

On VSTS, we have some files we want to protect on ***certain*** branches. How can one fail a merge/build if a particular file has changed?

First prize is to configure this on the build server, which in this case is VisualStudio.com (VSTS / GIT).

Scenario: we have various release branches v1, v2, v3. We want to protect the packages.json file to prevent anyone updating Nuget packages on these branches. So if the package.json file has changed on a pull request into "v3", don't allow the merge.

Comment: Are you using Git or TFVC for source control?

Comment: We are using Git

Answer (score 5):

For **Git**, you can protect a certain branch (not a certain file), then all the files exist in the branch will be protected.

You can use **Branch security** which users/groups can contribute for the branch.

Or you can use **Branch Policies** to protect not commit changes on the branch directly but use pull request to make changes etc.

Or you can **lock** a branch to prevent updating.

[image]

---

To expanded Starain's answer:

**First create a build definitio**n for the branch you want to protected (such as select `V3` branch in get sources step). And add a powershell task with the content below:

```
$head=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
$parents=$(git rev-list --parents -n 1 $head)
$p1,$p2,$p3=$parents.split(' ')
If ($p1 = $head)
{
  $parent1=$p2
  $parent2=$p3
}
ElseIf ($p2 = $head)
{
  $parent1=$p1
  $parent2=$p3
}
Else
{
  $parent1=$p1
  $parent2=$p2
}
$outp1=$(git diff $head $parent1 --name-only)
$outp2=$(git diff $head $parent2 --name-only)
If ($outp1 -contains 'package.json')
{
  echo "changed the specified file on the branch which contains commit $parent1"
  exit 1
}
If ($outp2 -contains 'package.json')
{
  echo "changed the specified file on the branch which contains commit $parent2"
  exit 1
}
```

So that when the file `package.json` has been change, powershell script will fail the build result.

**Then add the branch policy** for the branch which you want to protect.

Add build policy -> select the build definition you just created -> Policy requirement as Required -> Build expiration 0.1 hours (6 min) or other values since it’s every fast to queue a build with a powershell task -> save.

Comment: Locking the branch is not the solution I am looking for - but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do it in the build, simple workflow:

1. Configure branch policy for a succeed build required
2. Check whether the specific file changed in that build
3. Fail build if specific file has been changed

Comment: This is exactly what I want to do, how do you propose we check if the specific file changed or not? I.e. how do you do "change detection" on a build step. :)

Comment: @MarzSocks I expanded starain's answer with detail steps in my answer, you can have a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a required reviewer for a particular folder/file in VSTS for a particular branch.

In this way the person won't be able to check-in without getting an approval from the required reviewer.

[image]

Comment: Branch policies can protect certain branch(es), not for certain files/folders.

Comment: Branch policies with required reviewers and path filters can protect certain files in certain branches.

Comment: Yes, the automatically reviewers option can specify path, but for other options in Branch policies, it will protect the whole branch.

Comment: Unfortunately there is still the human element which leaves room for mistakes.

Comment: @MarzSocks You can assign it to a system/admin user which no one uses. I am just curious what is this scenario that you would never want this file to be changed?

Comment: Updated question with scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Git doesn't really work that way; individual files don't have any sort of security on them.

You could use a [`pre-commit hook`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks), but it's important to note that those hooks are client-side, not server-side -- each user would have to set up a pre-commit hook.

VSTS/TFS doesn't support Git server hooks (at least, not to the extent that it can block a push), otherwise a `pre-receive` or `update` hook would be exactly what you want.